# Constructing an exact sequence from a monomorphism using projective resolutions

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category (hence every object in $\mathcal{A}$ has a projective resolution), let $M$ and $N$ be two objects in $\mathcal{A}$. Consider the following commutative diagram [image]
where each row is a projective resolution and the existence of $f_0, f_1, \dots$ is given by comparison theorem.

Do we have the following or similar conclusion?

> The map $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if the following sequence is exact:
> $$
> \cdots \xrightarrow{} P_1\oplus Q_2 \xrightarrow{\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}
>     \epsilon _1&        0\\
>     -f_1&       \eta _2\\
> \end{smallmatrix} \right] } P_0\oplus Q_1 \xrightarrow{\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}
>     f_0&        \eta_1
> \end{smallmatrix} \right] } Q_0.
> $$

And how to prove that?

---

Enkidu told me I should consider Horseshoe lemma, but I don't know what to do.
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you just take $M$ and all the $P_i$ to be zero, your map is a monomorphism, but the sequence isn't necessarily exact.

Comment: @AchimKrause It is, because it is assumed to be a projective resolution of $N$.

Comment: Well, I meant that it still has homology in degree $0$ (the original sequence is exact everywhere, including degree $0$, if and only if $M\to N$ was an isomorphism). But I now realize that the question probably asked for "exact in positive degrees".

Comment: Ah, ok! :) I took the lack of an extra 0 on the right to mean that exactness at the Q_0 term was not required, and then everything is consistent. If you did ask for exactness there as well then your comment is correct, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that not every abelian category has enough projectives (e.g. $\mathscr A = \mathbf{FAb}$, the category of finite abelian groups, does not), but of course you're free [no pun intended] to *assume* that $\mathscr A$ has enough projectives.

Note that the complex
$$
\cdots \to P_1 \oplus Q_2 \to P_0 \oplus Q_1 \to M \oplus Q_0 \to N \to 0
$$
is exact, being the totalisation of a double complex with exact rows (the maps are the same matrices you wrote down, with the correct signs to make it a chain complex). It contains $0 \to M \to N \to 0$ as a subcomplex, and the quotient is the complex you describe. This gives a short exact sequence of chain complexes (written vertically):
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc} & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \cdots & \to & 0 & \to & 0 & \to & M & \to & N & \to & 0 \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \cdots & \to & P_1 \oplus Q_2 & \to & P_0 \oplus Q_1 & \to & M \oplus Q_0 & \to & N & \to & 0 \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & &  \downarrow\\ \cdots & \to & P_1 \oplus Q_2 & \to & P_0 \oplus Q_1 & \to & Q_0 & \to & 0 & \to & 0 \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0.\!\end{array}
$$
Taking the long exact homology sequence gives the result: the bottom sequence is exact at $P_0 \oplus Q_1$ if and only if $M \to N$ is injective. $\square$

Comment: Thank you very much!